# Обеззолачивание / обеззолочивание

Tags: орфография

Подскажите правильное современное написание слова!

Обеззолачивание или обеззолочивание (в смысле процесса удаления золота)?

Comment: Обычно золото *извлекают*, иногда *отделяют*, а где его *удаляют*, дайте адрес?

Comment: При обоззол**а**чивании золотосодержащих промывочных вод. Один раз в старой (до реформы орфографии) работе профессора Томского Политеха встретилось "обеззолочение (хлоридов)"; там же прилагательное _обеззолоченный_. В словарях не видно, гугл находит в патентной литературе.

Comment: @Alex_ander И все-таки, это процесс отделения золота или его удаления? (Думаю, если главное — повышение качества вод, то удаление, а если нас интересует золото, то отделение)

Comment: Процесс извлечения золота из воды или других веществ (при рафинировании золота).

Comment: Я так понимаю, что необычное слово указывает на этап расставания с отходами, которые не жалко после этого выбросить.

Comment: Получается, они *удаляют* остатки полезного из бесполезного(освобождают бесполезное от полезного), чтобы выбросить бесполезное? Акцент на бесполезном. Непривычный подход.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях слово не встречается, но в узкоспециальных текстах употребляется как термин. Если есть необходимость употребить такое слово, то можно соотнести его по типу словообразования со словарными глаголами, отличающимися только приставкой (оба есть у Даля): *озол**а**чивать* (несов. вид), *озолотить* (сов. вид). Логично просто добавить вторую приставку в отглагольное существительное *о(-без-)зол**а**чивание*. Вряд ли нужна парная форма от глагола сов. вида (первая форма универсальна, а попытки словообразования от глагола сов. вида не всегда удачны, например, жаргонизм "озвучание").